# MongoDB not querying `null` within a array at a given posision correctly

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I'm having a hard time understanding why the following happens within mongodb when dealing with nulls and array indexes within queries.

Say we have the following:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5852da24507d8c27f4e3c357"), "item" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5852da2d507d8c27f4e3c358"), "item" : { "something" : true } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5852da33507d8c27f4e3c359") }
```

When I try to find items that are null I get `ObjectId("5852da24507d8c27f4e3c357")` and `ObjectId("5852da33507d8c27f4e3c359")` which is as expected based on https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/

```
> db.test.find({"item" : null})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5852da24507d8c27f4e3c357"), "item" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5852da33507d8c27f4e3c359") }
```

But when I try to do the same but within a array with a given index, It's completely different set of results:

Say we have the following:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5852dbe1507d8c27f4e3c35c"), "a" : [ { "something" : true }, { "something" : true }, null ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5852dbf4507d8c27f4e3c35d"), "a" : [ { "something" : true }, { "something" : true }, { "something" : true } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5852dbfb507d8c27f4e3c35e"), "a" : [ { "something" : true }, { "something" : true } ] }
```

But If I do the query based on the index of 2 is null, we still get returned all the documents:

```
> db.test.find({"a.2": null})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5852dbe1507d8c27f4e3c35c"), "a" : [ { "something" : true }, { "something" : true }, null ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5852dbf4507d8c27f4e3c35d"), "a" : [ { "something" : true }, { "something" : true }, { "something" : true } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5852dbfb507d8c27f4e3c35e"), "a" : [ { "something" : true }, { "something" : true } ] }
```

This to me doesn't seem like its working as expected? But we can however see that the index position works correctly as we can do the following query:

```
> db.test.find({"a.2": {something:true}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5852dbf4507d8c27f4e3c35d"), "a" : [ { "something" : true }, { "something" : true }, { "something" : true } ] }
```

Is this a bug within mongodb and dealing with arrays and nulls?

Comment: I am not sure  if this is the expected behavior, perhaps a bug  so I created [JIRA SERVER-27442](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27442)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is even though you *mean* for `db.test.find({"a.2": null})` to be `query based on the index of 2 is null` that's not what it actually means.  What it means is *either* index of 2 is null or there is a field name `2` of the object which is null.   In array querying we reach into arrays (so saying `a:2` should match value `2` but also any array that has an element `2`.   Here the matcher is falling into the "I'm matching for subfield `2` but this is an array and therefore I should check every element of the array to see if it's field name `2`, value `null`.

This is an unfortunate ambiguity in the query language that makes the response not really incorrect in certain scenarios, and until the language is enhanced with syntax that allows you to unambiguously specify you are querying *only* for array position `2` or only for field name `2` querying `a.2` combined with `null` semantics will give the result you see.

Comment: Totally makes sense, and just tried it out too... didn't even realize I could have a document with a field on a number . Thanks for explaining what the query engine is doing behind the scenes! 

Comment: we will need to add syntax to query by position and syntax to query by name (that happens to be numeric) but in a way that's not backwards breaking - that's why it's not a simple or short term fix   :(